# Is it possible to create a function that creates smaller column than input column

Tags: r, monetdb

I'm working on a Monetdb Database with embedded R. Now, I want to process the data from a column, which basically reduces the amount of values.

The question now is if it is possible to create a R function that takes an input column with `n` values and returns a columns with `m` `(m <> n)`columns.

I tried it but the output of the function is somehow irritating:

```
-- create data
CREATE FUNCTION generate(n INTEGER) RETURNS TABLE(data DOUBLE) LANGUAGE R{
 data.frame(rnorm(n))
};

-- reduce data 
CREATE FUNCTION reduce(data REAL) returns DOUBLE LANGUAGE R{
 data[1:(length(data)-1)]
};

-- actually reduce generated data
select reduce(data) from generate(3);
```

This outputs the following:

```
sql>select reduce(data) from generate(3);
+--------------------------+
| L4                       |
+==========================+
|      -0.6561001539230347 |
|       1.0922646522521973 |
+--------------------------+
2 tuples (47.601ms)
```

The interesting think happens, when I add another column to the output:

```
sql>select 1,reduce(data) from generate(3);
+------+--------------------------+
| L4   | L6                       |
+======+==========================+
|    1 |      -1.2222824096679688 |
|    1 |        2.696558952331543 |
+------+--------------------------+
3 tuples (5.455ms)
```

The number of tuples which monetdb *thinks* to deliver changes. Is anything wrong with the Code or is it simply wrong to reduce the length of the output column?

This is only a simplified example of the real problem. The actual problem occurs when I insert the result into another table.

```
CREATE TABLE test(i INTEGER, r real);
insert into test select 1,reduce(data) from generate(3);
2 affected rows (4.404ms)
```

gives

```
select * from test;
GDK reported error.
BATproject: does not match always
```

What is the reason for the problem? I assume that it is somehow related to the above described problem.

Comment: Note: You definitely should change reduce to use `1:(length(data)-1)`. Right now it's actually doing `1:length(data)` and then subtracting 1 from each value of the vector. Typically this causes the first value of 0 to get get dropped but it's not doing what I think you intend it to do.

Comment: @Dason yes of course, thanks. Sometimes one need a second pair of eyes